# Laravel Query Bind and Unbind

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.6

Want to generate multiple results in a query.

```
    $now = Carbon::now();
    $currentStartDay = $now->startOfDay();
    $currentEndDay = $now->endOfDay();
    $currentStartWeek = $now->startOfWeek();
    $currentEndWeek = $now->endOfWeek();
    $currentStartMonth = $now->startOfMonth();
    $currentEndMonth = $now->endOfMonth();
    $currentStartYear = $now->startOfYear();
    $currentEndYear = $now->endOfYear();

    $query = DB::table('transactions AS t');

    $queryExpenseToday = $query;
    $queryExpenseWeek = $query;
    $queryExpenseMonth = $query;
    $queryExpenseYear = $query;

    dump($queryExpenseToday->whereBetween('t.created_at', [$currentStartDay, $currentEndDay])->toSql());
    dump($queryExpenseWeek->whereBetween('t.created_at', [$currentStartWeek, $currentEndWeek])->toSql());
    dump($queryExpenseMonth->whereBetween('t.created_at', [$currentStartMonth, $currentEndMonth])->toSql());
    dump($queryExpenseYear->whereBetween('t.created_at', [$currentStartYear, $currentEndYear])->toSql());
```

Problem and output are as follows:

1st dump

```
"select * from `transactions` as `t` where `t`.`created_at` between ? and ?"
```

2nd dump

```
"select * from `transactions` as `t` where `t`.`created_at` between ? and ? and `t`.`created_at` between ? and ?"
```

3rd dump

```
"select * from `transactions` as `t` where `t`.`created_at` between ? and ? and `t`.`created_at` between ? and ? and `t`.`created_at` between ? and ?"
```

4th dump

```
"select * from `transactions` as `t` where `t`.`created_at` between ? and ? and `t`.`created_at` between ? and ? and `t`.`created_at` between ? and ? and `t`.`created_at` between ? and ?"
```

The query is being appended, How to stop this?
Or how to unbind last binding parameter?

I am using Laravel 5.6

Looking for the best answer.

Comment: don't use the same query builder instance to build the query on

Comment: Actually, I have to use same query builder instance, my query/logic is not just simple I shown, is there any other way?

Comment: no you dont, but good luck

Comment: Can you show you're actual query/logic?

Comment: @RossWilson I don't think there is anything wrong with my query, there are a lot of joins, bind parameters like search/filter the results with pagination and my business logic, I am just stuck with the current problem if you can help... Thanks.

Comment: I wasn't thinking there was anything wrong with your queries but by your own admission it isn't as simple as the problem you have put in your question, I was merely asking as there might have been different / potentially more suitable approach than the one you currently have. That being said if you want to stick with your current solution that just use `clone` e.g. `$queryExpenseToday = clone $query;`.

Comment: Great man, you saved my day :-), just post your answer so I can mark it as done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is about reinstanciate the query? Instead of:

```
    ...
    $query = DB::table('transactions AS t');
    $queryExpenseToday = $query;
    $queryExpenseWeek = $query;
    ...
```

You could do:

```
    ...
    $query = DB::table('transactions AS t');
    $queryExpenseToday = DB::table('transactions AS t');
    $queryExpenseWeek = DB::table('transactions AS t');
    ...
```

Or you could clone it too:

```
    ...
    $query = DB::table('transactions AS t');
    $queryExpenseToday = clone($query);
    $queryExpenseWeek = clone($query);
    ...
```

The explanation is simple. When you use DB, it internally creates a new instance of Object, so if you use `$anyQuery=$query`, you're coping the reference to the same first Object. For that reason, you must create one new (first option) or clone it, that internally creates new one (second option)

You can use `dd($anyQuery)` to check it and play a little around the concept.
Good Look!

Answer (score 1):

The think is you are working here on objects, so in fact you are working on same instances.

So normally you can set common queries code, in your case it's just:

```
$query = DB::table('transactions AS t');
```

but then if you want to add different conditions to it and have multiple queries, you need to **clone** it so instead of:

```
$queryExpenseToday = $query;
$queryExpenseWeek = $query;
$queryExpenseMonth = $query;
$queryExpenseYear = $query;
```

you should use:

```
$queryExpenseToday = clone $query;
$queryExpenseWeek = clone $query;
$queryExpenseMonth = clone $query;
$queryExpenseYear = clone $query;
```

Of course you can do it in one line, so you can dump it like this too (and assign it to variable after you make sure it's really working):

```
dump((clone $query)->whereBetween('t.created_at', [$currentStartDay, $currentEndDay])->toSql());
```